# bash: :/root/dotnet: No such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, root, lxterminal

Whenever I open my terminal it shows me

`bash: :/root/dotnet: No such file or directory` on the first line

and `root@root:` on the second line.

How can I remove *bash: :/root/dotnet: No such file or directory* ?

Comment: Which version and release number of Linux are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Check your `~/.bashrc` there might line(s) mentioning `/root/dotnet` file or directory

```bsh
cat ~/.bashrc
```

If such entry exists then replace it with valid file or directory path instead of `/root/dotnet` or remove it if unnecessary